# Private Files on drupal

Tags: views, 7

I am using drupal 7.

I have uploaded pdf files into

**files/private**

Now I want that when I try to access

```
www.site.com/sites/default/files/private/q1-2014-fs.pdf
```

It will open. Only if user is activate then he can able to see file

I have created a `.htaccess` file too

in that

```
Deny from all

# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody tell me, where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Private Files download permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) module to set permission to download to certain users.

Also you can go for [Field Permission Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

Comment: These modules are actually irrelevant here,  What they will do, it to allow the admin to set up more fine-grained access control to file download of protected, private files. They will, however, do *nothing* to control access to *unprotected* files that can be accessed directly through by means of the URL.

Comment: @FreeRadical : Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

If the file is directly accessible by path or URL, then something is wrong.

It is not clear if you've set up Drupal to use the private access method for [File Access Control](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/cf_files.html#access), or just created the `files/private` path and hope that this will do it (it won't).

You need to set up the private file access method in Drupal.  Read through "[Working with files in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file)", and pay attention to the section "Managing file locations and access".

Please note that you should *not* create a `.htaccess` file yourself.  Drupal will do that for you when you set this up correctly through Drupal.  If you create this file yourself, you prevent Drupal from creating it.

Comment: i want to file not open by direct access

Comment: yes, sorry prevosly i did typo mistake

Comment: i created a private direcorty and uploading to private direcor. now url from node becomes 
http://localhost/mysite/system/files/q1-2014-fs.pdf, when i direct access it opens. i want only login user can

Comment: Thanks now it is creating url from node like
http://localhost/mysite/system/files/q1-2014-fs.pdf i can still able to access on broser

Comment: yes, i am able to access this file with node which is fine. but when i directly  add link to url. i am still able to open

Comment: "but when i directly add link to url. i am still able to open" - well then you've set it up wrong.  Your question has too little details about *how* you've set this up, and *how* you're testing it, to see where you go wrong in setting it up or testing.  Improve your question if you want more precise help than: RTFM (Read The Fine Manual).

Comment: In  simple words i am able to access this file by Anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

Your private files folder should be outside of drupal's structure as its public.

For example you'd want to structure it so that on your server you have a public_html directory with the drupal files in and then say private_files directory containing your private files, then in admin/config/media/file-system you should change the directory to point towards your new private folder.

Comment: It is obviously better if the private files folder is outside of the web root (having it outside Drupal's structure but still below the web root is not better). Unfortunately, on shared hosting, this setup is not always possible.  The private file access method in Drupal is safe enough when the private directory is below web root, provided you set it up right.  In this case the OP has obviously misconfigured his private access method (just by placing the `.htaccess` file shown in that directory, the configuration is messed up).